# Defining typescript types using parenthesis and square brackets, what's their meaning?

Tags: typescript

Which role are playing the square brackets and the parenthesis when defining new types in Typescript?
In the example below which should be the shape of the data for a variable with `typeThree`?

I played around with it and discovered the following so far.

```
type typeOne = { [id: string] : string; };
type typeTwo = { id : string; };
type typeThree = { (id: string) : string; };

let varOne: typeOne[] = [{id:'', id2:''}]; // OK
let varTwo: typeOne[] = [{idd:''}]; // OK

let varThree: typeTwo[] = [{idd:''}];  // error
let varFour: typeTwo[] = [{id:'', id2:''}]; // error
let varFive: typeTwo[] = [{idd:''}];  // error
let varSix: typeTwo[] = [{id:''}];  // OK
```

- `typeOne` seems to describe an array of maps whose keys and values are strings
- `typeTwo` seems to describe an array of maps `{id: 'any string'}` must only contain one key called `id`
- `typeThree` I don't know what it is describing.

Comment: Might it not be easier to start by *reading the docs*, which introduce and explain the syntax, than randomly experimenting and attempting to infer the semantics? For one thing, none of those three define arrays, you subsequently type your variables *as arrays of those things*. You have defined an object with any key, an object with the key id, and a function. See e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: If others find this, like me, when looking for information about types that use square brackets like this: `function blah(): [string, boolean]`, then _that_ particular example is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you are using the `type` keyword, the documentation on interfaces will apply to each of your examples. Both `type` and `interface` work in the same way, but you can't use a `type` for heritage.

## Indexers

Allows a map with arbitrary string keys. In the example below the keys must be a string ([numbers are also allowed](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/11/typescript-index-signatures-not-type-checked/) so technically it is `id: string | number` although you aren't allowed to explicitly state that) and the value must be a string (and only a string).

```
// Defines an indexer
// The id(or key) must be a string, or number.
// The value must be a string.
type TypeOne = { [id: string]: string; };

const a: TypeOne = {};
a['key'] = 'value';

// Example type violation Type '3' is not assignable to type 'string'
a['key'] = 3;
```

Indexers are described in the [interface section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) of the handbook.

## Object

The second type in your question is an object structure. It requires an object to have the named property, with an appropriately typed value. When creating an instance of the type using a literal, you'll get assisted with unknown properties (which aren't allowed) which helps to catch mis-spellings.

```
type TypeTwo = { id: string; };

const a: TypeTwo = { 
    id: 'value'
} 

// Object literal must only specify known values
const b: TypeTwo = { 
    id: 'value',
    nmae: 'value'
} 

// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
const c: TypeTwo = { 
    id: 4
}
```

## Function

The third type in your question describes a function. Examples below, including the sometimes mysterious case of example `b`, which is valid even though it doesn't have an `id` parameter. The logic on that one is that if you ignore the parameter in the function body, why force it in the signature. Calling code may supply it, but you aren't using it anyway.

```
type TypeThree = (id: string) => string;

const a: TypeThree = (id: string) => {
    return id;
};

const b: TypeThree = () => {
    return 'value';
}

// Types of parameters 'id' and 'id' are incompatible.
const c: TypeThree = (id: number) => {
    return 'value';
}

// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
const d: TypeThree = (id: string) => {
    return 5;
}
```

See [function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types) in the handbook.

Comment: I think we are not describing the same type three, but the other two explanations were helpful